# Exporting existing uploaded images in Refinery to Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, refinerycms, refinery

I have an existing Rails RefineryCMS application, which have been running for quite some time. It has alot of image and document uploads, which always have been uploaded to the local filesystem.

But we are moving to Heroku, then this will be a problem, since Heroku doesn't persist these files.

So, we need to get all the existing images and document exported to a Amazon S3.

How could we achieve this?

Would it be plain simple as just copying over the existing files from the current production environment to the S3 bucket?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The plain solution was just to copy the existing folders that are generated by fileupload from Dragonfly in "app/public" to Amazon S3.